# AOSP Building Failed - ckati failed with: exit status 1

Tags: android, android-source, google-coral, naos-project

So I've been working to build Android AOSP project. I followed the guidelines on the official documentation (https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading).
After several tries, i always got the below error stack trace from the terminal. I'm trying to build **'aosp_coral-userdebug'**. Another thing I noticed is that, if I use another combo from the menu, I also get another form of error with **'ninja'**.
Help please!!!

````
12:09:31 You are building on a machine with 15.4GB of RAM
12:09:31 
12:09:31 The minimum required amount of free memory is around 16GB,
12:09:31 and even with that, some configurations may not work.
12:09:31 
12:09:31 If you run into segfaults or other errors, try reducing your
12:09:31 -j value.
12:09:31 ************************************************************
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=S
PLATFORM_VERSION=S
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_coral
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-5.4.0-47-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-18.04.5-LTS
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=AOSP.MASTER
OUT_DIR=out
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=hardware/google/av hardware/google/camera hardware/google/interfaces hardware/google/pixel device/google/coral hardware/qcom/sm8150/display hardware/qcom/sm8150/data/ipacfg-mgr hardware/qcom/sm8150/gps vendor/google/airbrush/floral vendor/google/biometrics/face vendor/google/camera vendor/google/darwinn vendor/qcom/sm8150 vendor/qcom/sm8150/proprietary/commonsys/telephony-apps/DataStatusNotification vendor/qcom/sm8150/proprietary/data/permissions vendor/qcom/sm8150/proprietary/gps vendor/qcom/sm8150/codeaurora/location vendor/google/interfaces vendor/qcom/sensors vendor/google/tools/sensors vendor/qcom/sm7250/codeaurora/commonsys/telephony/ims/ims-ext-common vendor/qcom/sm7250/codeaurora/dataservices/rmnetctl vendor/qcom/sm7250/proprietary/commonsys/qcrilOemHook vendor/qcom/sm7250/proprietary/commonsys/telephony-apps/ims vendor/qcom/sm7250/proprietary/commonsys/telephony-apps/QtiTelephonyService vendor/qcom/sm7250/proprietary/commonsys/telephony-apps/xdivert vendor/qcom/sm7250/proprietary/qcril-data-hal vendor/qcom/sm7250/proprietary/qcril-hal
============================================
wildcard(out/target/product/coral/clean_steps.mk) was changed, regenerating...
[ 99% 1236/1237] finishing build rules ...
FAILED: 
build/make/core/main.mk:1336: warning:  device/google/coral/aosp_coral.mk produces files inside build/make/target/product/generic_system.mks artifact path requirement. 
Offending entries:
system/etc/permissions/com.qti.snapdragon.sdk.display.xml
system/framework/com.qti.snapdragon.sdk.display.jar
system/framework/com.qualcomm.qti.uceservice-V2.0-java.jar
system/framework/vendor.qti.hardware.alarm-V1.0-java.jar
system/framework/vendor.qti.hardware.data.latency-V1.0-java.jar
system/framework/vendor.qti.hardware.factory-V1.0-java.jar
system/framework/vendor.qti.ims.callinfo-V1.0-java.jar
system/framework/vendor.qti.voiceprint-V1.0-java.jar
system/lib/libDiagService.so
system/lib/libOpenCL_system.so
system/lib/libadsprpc_system.so
system/lib/libcdsprpc_system.so
system/lib/libdiag_system.so
system/lib/libdisplayconfig.so
system/lib/libmdsprpc_system.so
system/lib/libmmosal.so
system/lib/libqmi_cci_system.so
system/lib/libsdsprpc_system.so
system/lib64/libDiagService.so
system/lib64/libOpenCL_system.so
system/lib64/libadsprpc_system.so
system/lib64/libcdsprpc_system.so
system/lib64/libdiag_system.so
system/lib64/libdisplayconfig.so
system/lib64/libmdsprpc_system.so
system/lib64/libmmosal.so
system/lib64/libqmi_cci_system.so
system/lib64/libsdsprpc_system.so
build/make/core/main.mk:1336: error: Build failed.
12:10:42 ckati failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (02:25 (mm:ss)) ####```
````

Comment: The warnings at the beginning of the log seem pretty serious. Why not run the build with low parallelization (lower `j` value) or in a big fat VM in the cloud?

Comment: It's not serious and it's nothing but informational.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means the build process was killed by the OS in your laptop due to having no RAM left.
You can confirm by running dmesg after the error and seeing in kernel logs that your process got killed.

Solutions would be:

1. Run make with a smaller j value than you're currently using, or
2. Get more RAM, or
3. Add swap space ( disk part that will be used as virtual memory)

Comment: _You are building on a machine with 15.4GB of RAM. The minimum required amount of free memory is around 16GB, and even with that, some configurations may not work. If you run into segfaults or other errors, try reducing your -j value._ If my build process starts with that, I'd buy that RAM first.. even if it failed for a missing semicolon.

Comment: Yeah, long-term, it'd be best to go with a RAM increase. Short-term, either of the other two solution should solve the issue.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Having low ram is not an error and 15.4 GB is often still plenty. The error in question is `FAILED: build/make/core/main.mk:1336: warning:  device/google/coral/aosp_coral.mk produces files inside build/make/target/product/generic_system.mks artifact path requirement. Offending entries:`

Comment: That's a warning only.

Comment: This error is not related to the RAM size. It might be related to the offending entries, meaning conflicts between applications and packages you are building along with your project.